# Where do I get deeper information about the origin of anatomical names?

Tags: terminology, anatomy

When I am learning anatomy, I sometimes wonder "why does this structure is called like that". For instance: Today I found out where atlas and axis got there names from. Wikipedia told me "The bone is named for Atlas of Greek mythology, for just as Atlas bore the weight of the heavens, the first cervical vertebra supports the head."

But sometimes I'm not so lucky. For example, I once tried to find out why the Margos of the scapula are called "margo", but the Crista iliaca is called a crista. It also looks like a margo to me.

Or why the Fovea articularis at the proximal radius is called "fovea" and not "fossa" (Or more generall, what is the difference between a fovea, a fossa and a facies).

Or if there is a system, wich bone is called first in a name of a joint; why is it "Articulatio sacroiliaca" and not "Articulatio iliasacralis"?

So I wonder; is there a book or a website or some other source, where the meaning of the names is explained more in depth? (and not just the names, also maybe the history to it - if there is a significant one)

thank you for your help -
a medical student in his first year.

Comment: Most of them are explained by any good Latin dictionary. As of joint nomenclature...most can be called either way, although the general consensus seems to move towards "whatever comes first in the alphabet first", with old habits dying slowly (if ever).

Comment: A decent dictionary will give the Latin/Greek roots of anatomical terms.  A [*fovea*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=fovea) and a [*fossa*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=fossa) are different structures. Etymology online gives more info than you asked for. Fyi #1: this is an English Language network (except the foreign language sites); in English, it's the sacroiliac joint (adjective before the noun), whereas in Romance languages, it's often the reverse, and you seem to be referring to joints/etc. in a Romance language. Fyi #2: One question per question is the norm. The [tour] helps.

Comment: thank you two for your answers. That helped a lot.
I will also use the information on how to write better questions.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking - I think "whatever comes first in the alphabet first". re. naming joints is incorrect. I would *think* that joints are named relative to their position, with closer to the center coming first. Tibiofibular, radiocarpal, metacarpophalangeal, lumbosacral, sacroiliac, atlanto-occipital, glenohumeral, sternoclavicular, sternomanubrial, and a few others, though I can think of opposites, e.g. temperomandibular, achromioclavicular... too much time on my hands, I think.